# Fatal error: 'break' not in the 'loop' or 'switch' context in

Tags: php, wordpress

I've setup a wordpress blog (I imported the db) and it's throwing this **error**

> Fatal error: 'break' not in the 'loop' or 'switch' context in
>   /home/kbuzz/webapps/kb_blog/wp-content/plugins/types/embedded/common/toolset-forms/lib/adodb-time.inc.php
>   on line 1012

The code is below from line `1004` to `1013`

```
function adodb_tz_offset($gmt,$isphp5)
{
    $zhrs = abs($gmt)/3600;
    $hrs = floor($zhrs);
    if ($isphp5) 
        return sprintf('%s%02d%02d',($gmt<=0)?'+':'-',floor($zhrs),($zhrs-$hrs)*60); 
    else
        return sprintf('%s%02d%02d',($gmt<0)?'+':'-',floor($zhrs),($zhrs-$hrs)*60); 
    break;
}
```

Comment: remove break from the code, why you need break in function

Comment: @ChetanAmeta thanks fixed it

Answer (score 79):

**PHP 5.x.x**, a `break` statement outside a `for`, `foreach`, `while` or `switch` statement **DID NOT** throw an error message and was syntactically okay.

**PHP 7.0 and higher**, a `break` statement is no longer permitted outside a `for`, `foreach`, `while` or `switch` statement and gives a fatal error.

Example code:

```
<?php
if (2 == 1 + 1) {
    echo "Dummy Example of break inside if condition";
    break; // - Valid in php 5.*
           // - Gives a Fatal error in PHP 7.*.*:
           // "Fatal error: 'break' not in the 'loop' or 'switch' context in ... "
}
?>
```

Comment: This answer is partially correct but caused me to waste a lot of time tracking down the wrong issue.  break and continue are still allowed in while loops as well.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to fix the problem by commenting out the (useless) break statement in the offending .php file.

Comment: is there an alternative then? something to prevent the rest of the script from running?

Comment: @davewhirlwind he didn't say it wasn't allowed within while loops :) so still a correct answer. but why isn't this marked as the answer?

Comment: @Anthony you could use an if/else statement? A return false if you're in a function? etc.. multiple good options imho.

Comment: Is there a reason for this? break's commonly used in exactly this way to prevent a loop that doesn't need to run anymore. Why would the PHP team take this tool out of developer hands?

Comment: It is still permitted inside for, while and switch statements. It is NOT permitted else where.

Answer (score 30):

look at the `break;`

replace with

`return false;`

in your code and it will work.

Comment: I think this is a more general answer. With some explanation it will become the best answer.

In my case I have:
`function do_something() { if ($condition) { <code block 1> } else { break; } <code block 2> }`

If I just remove the `break`, <code block 2> will be executed. With `return false;` <code block 2> will not be executed.

Answer (score 11):

Removing `break` fixed it

```
function adodb_tz_offset($gmt,$isphp5)
{
   $zhrs = abs($gmt)/3600;
    $hrs = floor($zhrs);
if ($isphp5) 
    return sprintf('%s%02d%02d',($gmt<=0)?'+':'-',floor($zhrs),($zhrs-$hrs)*60); 
else
    return sprintf('%s%02d%02d',($gmt<0)?'+':'-',floor($zhrs),($zhrs-$hrs)*60); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `return false;` instead of `break;` or `exit();` or `continue;` This prevent the rest of the script from running but will continue the loop if at all the rule still true