# Use of break after return

Tags: php, break, idioms

A website I was visiting failed with

> Fatal error: 'break' not in the 'loop' or 'switch' context in `FILE` on line `N`

Looking at the source code (found via filename / path - it's an older version of some open source code) showed **many** functions similar to this:

```php
class Clazz {
  // stuff
  public static function foo($bar) {
    // some code without loops/return
    return 'baz';
    break; // This is line N
  }
}
```

Now I know that a `break` outside of a loop or switch context [was allowed in PHP 5 but is no longer since PHP 7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36509974/1116364), hence the error message.

My questions is: **Why would you put a `break` after a return anyway?** Is/was this some (outdated) idiom?

I've found this pattern in multiple functions in multiple different code bases now; so it doesn't seem like an "left-over" from a refactoring or a misunderstanding of a single developer to me..?

Comment: That makes no sense to me either. Very strange.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't something like `if (x) return; break;` where the return was conditional and might be skipped?  If not, then as far as I know that code will never make sense.  What are some of these code bases?  If they are all local to your work it could be the work of one (strange) employee.

Comment: This is redundant code.But Compiler didn't regard it as an error.
I think since it was executable for long time, everyone has left it.

Comment: @treyBake  - no, here the return (supposedly) does not come after a conditional so it always executes.  In your link the return might not execute and the question is about whether the return by itself is enough to exit the function.

Comment: @DaveS the return wasn't conditional in these functions; code is multiple different open source projects (i add some links to the question asap). Searching for the error message brings up various wordpress plugins for example.

Comment: Because it surfaced in multiple code bases I thought it could be some idiom .. or useful trick for testing / debugging

Comment: No, it has never been meaningful. Are these public code bases, or just in your organization? It's probably a snippet that was written once (who knows why?) and then copied without noticing the mistake.

Comment: Regarding possible refactoring leftovers, maybe those functions used to be cases in a switch? That's the only context where I've really seen people use break after return, even though it's pointless. Just a guess

Answer (score 0):

Code after `return` statement will never be executed, then that break is useless.

I would imagine that developers ware testing functions, and they forgot deleting that code, as `will never be executed` then, there were no problems by that times.

For refactoring that code, just ignore it (delete), cause it had never work.

Comment: I mean, don't refactor that code. because it dont work