# Fatal error: 'continue' not in the 'loop' or 'switch' context

Tags: php, wordpress

I am fairly sure that this error is caused by a PHP update, similar to this post ([Fatal error: 'break' not in the 'loop' or 'switch' context in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34871198/fatal-error-break-not-in-the-loop-or-switch-context-in)), I just don't know how to correct the code.

I'm getting this error:

> Fatal error: 'continue' not in the 'loop' or 'switch' context in [template name] on line 32

Here is the code on line 32:

```
<h2><a href="<?php if(is_wp_error( $term_link )) {continue;} else {echo esc_url( $term_link );}  ?>"><?php echo $term_name; ?></a></h2>
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Why do you need a `continue` that is not part of a loop? In which scenario does that make sense?

Comment: Remove `continue;`.

Comment: continue and break statements are the parts of a loop. Here you are not using any loop. please make sure you are using the loop ( for , while ).

Comment: I removed the entire line of code. Everything seems to be working fine now. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

You making this too complicated. Just invert the condition:

```
<h2><a href="<?php if (!is_wp_error( $term_link )) { echo esc_url( $term_link ); }  ?>"><?php echo $term_name; ?></a></h2>
```